# Can an UDF from pyspark return an object different from a column?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I want to apply some functions to the columns of a pysaprk dataframe, a manage to do this with UDF, but I want the return to be another object diffent than a column of the dataframe, a pandas dataframe, a python list, etc.

I am using a classifier to divide each column into classes, but I want the result to be a summary of the classes, not the pyspark dataframe modify, I don't know if this is posible with UDF

My code goes like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyspark 
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType, FloatType, DoubleType
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)

df_pd = pd.DataFrame(
    data={ 'Income':[12.0,45.0,24.0,24.0,54.0],
           'Debt':[23.0,4.0,1.0,6.0,3.0]} )
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(df_pd)


# function
def clase(x):
    #n = np.mean(df_pd[name])
    #n = np.mean(df_pd["Ingresos"])
    n = 30
    m = 20
    if x>=n:
        x="good"
    elif x>=m:
        x="regular"
    else:
        x="bad"
    return x

# UDF
clase_udf = udf(lambda z: clase(z), StringType())

(
    df.select('Income',
              'Debt',
              clase_udf('Income').alias('new') )
    .show()
)
```

This gives the next table:

```
+------+----+-------+
|Income|Debt|    new|
+------+----+-------+
|  12.0|23.0|    bad|
|  45.0| 4.0|   good|
|  24.0| 1.0|regular|
|  24.0| 6.0|regular|
|  54.0| 3.0|   good|
+------+----+-------+
```

What I want is to get something like this:

```
+-------+------------+
| Clases| Description|
+-------+------------+
|   good|   30<Income|
|regular|20<Income<30|
|    bad|   Income<20|
+-------+------------+
```

Like a summary of the clases

Comment: You don't need a `udf` to get the `new` column. Still, it's unclear to me what you're asking. Do you want to derive the `Description` from the data? But you specified the cuts for `good, bad, regular` ...

Comment: How does the desired output relate to your input at all? If you already know `m` and `n`, why not just do `spark.createDataFrame([('good', '30<Income'), ('regular', '20<Income<30'), ('bad', 'Income<20')], ["Clases", "Description"])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a udf and return a **StringType** too :

I put your constant out, in case you want it to be global and modify it for multiple functions at one.

```
n = 30
m = 20

def description(x):
    if x >= n:
        x = str(n) + " < Income"
    elif x >= m:
        x = str(m) + " < Income < " + str(n)
    else:
        x = "Income < " + str(m)
    return x

description_udf = udf(lambda z: description(z), StringType())

df.select(
    clase_udf('Income').alias('Clases'),
    description_udf("Income").alias("Description")
).distinct().show()
```

The output is :

[image]

Comment: Yes, sorry by the mistake.

Comment: But what I want it´s just a table like the last one, not all the datframe with the description

Comment: Just change your select by taking the columns you want. I edited the post

Comment: Ah okay you want something that is not correlated at all to your data. Okay I edited again. Just use "distinct"

Comment: I am wondering if there is a better way to do it, because I understand that the UDF is making the whole column and then get the different elements